# how to get Username by id in identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to get the user name by id and pass it to view by viewbag.
I can access the user by id but I can't access the user name.
I'm using identity 3 in asp.net core.
This is my action:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var userCourse = _courseService.GetUserCourse(id);
        var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        return View(userCourse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    var userCourse = _courseService.GetUserCourse(id);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    ViewBag.UserName= user.UserName;
    return View(userCourse);
}
```

And in View use viewbag.UserName to render userName

```
<label>User Name:</label>  @ViewBag.UserName
```

Comment: thank you but It's not working.it has problem in user.UserName.the UserName has red underline.

Comment: Look into the return Type of  FindByIdAsync(id) method. and find the appropriate  property  used instead of UserName and use that one

Comment: There is no property for that.just there are result,wait,status and etc.There is no field such as username or email or phone ,etc

Comment: var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id).Result; replace this line and then check